# How to wire this into new IKEA fitting?

Tags: electrical, wiring, light-fixture

When I was looking at other questions of other people asking about IKEA fitting most just had 3 wires. However non of these match what I have in my house, where would I begin to start fitting my new ikea one. Or is it just easier to find an electrician?

Thanks in advance x[image]

Comment: What do you have in your house that is different?  Add pictures to the question so we can see the difference.

Comment: what is it, what does it do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a standard UK ceiling rose arrangement (plenty of images available online).

- All earths stay connected together (bare wires with green/yellow sleeve). If the fitting has any metal parts, they will be connected to that.
- Three blue neutrals stay connected together. One from the previous light, one to the next light, and one to power this light.
- Three brown lives stay connected together. One from the previous light, one to the next light, one to the switch.
- The remaining two wires are the switched lives. The blue with brown sleeve comes from the switch and the brown goes to this light. Consider labelling these (all the others can be simply grouped by colour in your case).

You need to retain these connections or your lights and switches won't work. This arrangement needs quite a bit of space within the light fitting and might not always be achievable (easily or at all). Some fittings come with similar connectors to the ones you already have, but others will only provide a way to connect a single incoming cable (live, neutral and earth) and you will need you to add or substitute your own connectors to keep the other wires together (e.g. terminal strips or Wago connectors). If there's really no space in the light fitting, you may need to fit a recessed box or junction box up in the ceiling (which would need to remain accessible for future inspection).

Comment: So being able to Wire this into the IKEA fitting I bought which consist of just a live and neutral wire is a little bit of a process?